# How to factory reset my phone via my pc when i cannot get a start up logo on the screen on my phone

Tags: samsung

When I dropped my phone the screen showed some weird colours on upper right corner. I replaced the screen.  Now by using the recommended three button sequence the led in upper left corner comes on for a few seconds as well as the home button and the other two lights up and then go out. I call the phone and it vibrates but screen remains black. Can I reset the phone using my PC? How can this be done when I cannot get any response from the screen OR is the mother board at fault?

Answer (score 1):

A factory reset won't do you any good. This is hardware damage somewhere else in the phone and it needs to be brought to an electronics repair shop or sent to the manufacturer.